# What checks and balances are there to stop the Supreme Court from grossly misinterpreting the constitution?

Tags: united-states, law, constitution, supreme-court, separation-of-powers

If the Supreme Court were to rule that they have the power to impeach and convict the president because they are supposed to make sure the constitution is not violated or ruling that the first amendment only applied to members of popular political groups, would there be anything anyone could do about it or would the police just start being able to jail members of 3rd parties?

Comment: I've added the [tag:united-states] tag as I was assuming that was the country you were asking about.  If that is incorrect, please replace that tag with the tag for the relevant country.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the Congress deems the misinterpretation of the Constitution to be an abuse of power, then the House of Representatives can impeach any or all of the Justices of the court, and the Senate can, with a two-thirds majority, remove them from their positions.

Once the Senate has confirmed their replacements (possibly sooner), a new case can be brought to nullify the previous ruling.

Comment: Abe Fortas resigned while being threatened with the same. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abe_Fortas#Ethics_scandal_and_resignation

Comment: I guess by "Archibald" you're referring to [Robert Wodrow Archbald](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Wodrow_Archbald) but he was not on the Supreme Court, although he did sit on the short-lived [United States Commerce Court](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Commerce_Court) and simultaneously on the Court of Appeals for the Third Circuit,

Comment: I would upvote this except for the error about Robert Wodrow Archbald. A  mention of Abe Fortas would be a plus.I am reluctant to edit someoen else's answer in such a way.